# SQL query problem for getting the details under a individual date or date range from datetime

Tags: mysql, sql

The sql query I have is :

```
Select count(cf_1519) as service_up,createdtime
from  vtiger_ticketcf,vtiger_crmentity
Where date(createdtime)=date(now()) and 
      vtiger_ticketcf.cf_1519 like 'service up%' and 
      vtiger_crmentity.crmid = vtiger_ticketcf.ticketid"
```

which gives result as

[image]

again if i want to search the result individualyl by the query :

```
Select count(cf_1519) as service_up,createdtime
from  vtiger_ticketcf,vtiger_crmentity
Where date(createdtime)= '16/10/2019%' and
      vtiger_ticketcf.cf_1519 like 'service up%' and 
      vtiger_crmentity.crmid = vtiger_ticketcf.ticketid"
```

the result is not similar similar to previous :

[image]

I want to get the result by individual search by date only or a date range , i dont need the time
what changes in the sql code is needed to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Your second query should look more like this:

```
select count(cf_1519) as service_up, max(createdtime)
from  vtiger_ticketcf t join
      vtiger_crmentity c
      on c.crmid = t.ticketid
Where date(createdtime) = '2019-10-16' and
      t.cf_1519 like 'service up%';
```

Notes:

- You have an aggregation query (because of the `count()`, but have extraneous columns.  All columns should be aggregated, except for those in the `group by` (and there are none).
- *Never* use commas in the `from` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- You seem to want to use string functions on dates.  I have never seen a date with a percentage sign in it.
- Use proper date/time functions on date/time values, not string functions.

Comment: *"Use proper date/time functions on date/time values, not string functions."* Topicstarter If this is not possible to change as there already might be running application(s) using this table try `where date(STR_TO_DATE(LEFT(createdtime, 10), '%Y/%m/%d')) = '2019-10-16'` instead as "workaround" for the wrong datatype usage..